# In PHP, is there a function like stristr, but for arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

Basically, I have an array of strings to search for. If it were only one string, `stristr` would work perfectly. However, since it's an array, the only thing I can think of is to just run a foreach loop and `stristr` the string from each iteration.

Surely there's a better way to do this, I just don't know it.

### Edit

For example, say I have this array:

`$array = array("string1", "foo", "bar", doowop");`

and this string:

`$string = "aw dang man lets go to that bar";`

I need to figure out if `$string` contains one of the strings from the array.

Comment: stristr doesn't just search, but returns part of the string. So please clarify your question - do you need to check if the string (haystack) contains any of the strings in the array, or if you need to check if it contains all of them, or what?

Comment: @MarkBaker: You're thinking of `stripos()`.  It does return a portion of the string, either before or after the matched needle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you will have to foreach through the array, as the point of the stristr function is the return value.

Comment: Well, damn. Just seems kind of inefficient.

Comment: Yep, seems inefficient, but I guess it is negligible if the size of the array is not hundreds of thousands of elements ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The nearest is `array_search` ([docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)) but it's not case-insensitive. Or `array_keys` ([docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)). You don't say which you want -- the former will stop as soon as it finds a match; the latter will return all matches.

Comment: If you lowercase the criteria as well as the array with strtolower(), then it would become case-insensitive.

Comment: `array_search` uses an array, and you can't lowercase an entire array with `strtolower()`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a callback. For exampe there are functions like `array_map` or `array_walk` or `array_walk_recursive`. Have a look at http://ch2.php.net/manual/de/book.array.php

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

There's `array_search` and `in_array` but both of those are case-sensitive. You could do it like this:

```
$new_array = array_flip($your_array); //exchange keys for values
$new_array = array_change_key_case($new_array); // lowercases everything
$new_array = array_flip($new_array); // exchanges your values back
$your_key = array_search($needle, $new_array);

$original_value = $your_array[$your_key];
```

Don't know if that's really that much better than just looping :)

Answer (score 0):

You can consider **[preg_grep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php)** function and I think this will exactly solve your problem. You can also have a look on **[array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)**, **[array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)**, **[array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)**, **[substr_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)**, **[array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)** and **[in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)** functions if **preg_grep** does not solve your problem.